# KIBANA - CODIGO QUERY CONSOLA A VISUALIZAR EN CANVAS O VISUALIZE

Tags: kibana

Llevo poco utilizando Kibana, disculpad si la pregunta no es del todo correcta
tengo un codigo de query en la consola de Dev Tools de Kibana y quiero visualizar el resultado en alguna tabla o similar
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y enseñarnos el código por favor? Sería más fácil ayudarte si lo haces, y así la gente se volcará a hacerlo